# Modern haskell implementation of generically derived bifunctors

Tags: haskell, functor, generic-programming, deriving, bifunctor

I'm looking for a way to derive `fmapFirst` and `fmapSecond` for bifunctors automatically. I would prefer a way to do it using the new `Generic` type class or using `Data.Data`, and without Template Haskell.

(Note that I already know that https://hackage.haskell.org/package/genifunctors-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Generics-Genifunctors.html supports this with use of Template Haskell, I wish to know if Template Haskell can be avoided here)

Comment: Ask this question somewhere else. Questions about software recommendations, including library recommendations, are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Your question doesn't typecheck in my brain. Haskell can automatically derive class instances (like `Eq`, or `Functor`) but never member functions. Those derivations are provided by the compiler (after using a suitable pragma like  `DeriveFunctor`), never by a package. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HansLub Check this out: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/genifunctors-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Generics-Genifunctors.html . I want something like this but without Template Haskell if possible.

Comment: Ah, I see. Template Haskell can 'generate'  class instance declarartions; your use of the word "derive" made my head explode (but [you're not the only one](https://github.com/ekmett/bifunctors/issues/17). It is still not clear to me what you mean by 'derive' _outside_ the context of TH (as you want to avoid it)

Comment: @HansLub - I mean that maybe it can be implemented generically by using properties of other generic programming oriented type classes (Data.Data and Generic)

Comment: [The generic-deriving package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving) mentions a paper "A generic deriving mechanism for Haskell". Seems I will have to read it to prevent future brain explosions :-)

Comment: This question can be edited to be on-topic for StackOverflow. Instead of asking for library recommendations, you can ask how to do something specific like, "I'm trying to derive `fmapFirst` and `fmapSecond` for bifunctors ...". It's helpful if you include what you have done so far or references to what you have found researching the problem. If a solution exists in a library, you might still get an answer referring to that library, but a good answer will also include how that library works. This should be more useful to you and more useful to future readers of StackOverflow.

Comment: The closest thing I know of is the derived `GFunctor` in [`Generics.Deriving.Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.7.0/docs/Generics-Deriving-Functor.html), which solves both halves of the problem, leaving only a problem of juggling two type arguments.